# XSLT: how do I parse a document to retain only interesting nodes, along with all parents, at any depth?

Tags: xslt

Given a document as below:

```
<root>
<a>
    <b>
        <c>Sometext</c>
    </b>
    <b>
        <d/>
    </b>
    <b>
        <e>
            <f>Some interesting__text some more</f>
        </e>
    </b>
</a>
<h>
    <g>Another piece of very_interesting__text</g>
</h>
</root>
```

I would like to get the following out:

```
<root>
<a>
    <b>
        <e>
            <f>Some interesting__text some more</f>
        </e>
    </b>
</a>
<h>
    <g>Another piece of very_interesting__text</g>
</h>
<interesting>interesting__text</interesting>
<interesting>very_interesting__text</interesting>
</root>
```

Essentially, I need to get out all the parent nodes of any node which contains interesting text, which can be matched using regex `\w+__\w+`.
As a bonus, I would like to get all the interesting pieces added somewhere at the end of my document.

The nodes which can contain the interesting pieces can be named anything, so any dependencies on specific node names cannot be part of a solution.

I'm thinking XSLT is a good way to get at this, but am having trouble putting together a stylesheet. Obviously, I could do this in code, but would prefer a stylesheet as I am already using others in my script, so this would simplify things some.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: There was an error in the sample XML, where a comment asked why a  tag was being transformed to an  tag - this is now corrected in the above.

Comment: Can you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 to have regular expression support? And why has the second `f` been transformed to `h`, is that another part of the problem? Can we assume that the text is in complete text nodes, as in your example, or is `<f>Some in<span>teres</span>ting__text more stuff</f>` also possible?

Comment: As edited: the f to h transformation was en error on my part. The text can be assumed to be in complete text nodes, so `<f>Some in<span>teres</span>ting__text more stuff</f>` does not have to be solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my XSLT 2.0 suggestion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="pattern" select="'\w+__\w+'"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="text" select="//text()[matches(., $pattern)]"/>
<xsl:variable name="nodes" select="$text/ancestor-or-self::node()"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()[$nodes intersect .]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$text" mode="interesting"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()[$nodes intersect .]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="interesting">
  <interesting><xsl:value-of select="."/></interesting>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using Saxon 9.5, it transforms

```
<root>
<a>
    <b>
        <c>Sometext</c>
    </b>
    <b>
        <d/>
    </b>
    <b>
        <e>
            <f>Some interesting__text some more</f>
        </e>
    </b>
</a>
<f>
    <g>Another piece of very_interesting__text</g>
</f>
</root>
```

into

```
<root>
   <a>
      <b>
         <e>
            <f>Some interesting__text some more</f>
         </e>
      </b>
   </a>
   <f>
      <g>Another piece of very_interesting__text</g>
   </f>
   <interesting>Some interesting__text some more</interesting>
   <interesting>Another piece of very_interesting__text</interesting>
</root>
```

The sample nodes don't have attribute, if they can have them in the real XML then add the template

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

To filter the text nodes in the collection of `interesting` elements you can use `analyze-string` so by changing the template for `text()` to

```
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="interesting">
  <interesting>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$pattern}">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </interesting>
</xsl:template>
```

the result is changed to

```
<root>
   <a>
      <b>
         <e>
            <f>Some interesting__text some more</f>
         </e>
      </b>
   </a>
   <f>
      <g>Another piece of very_interesting__text</g>
   </f>
   <interesting>interesting__text</interesting>
   <interesting>interesting__text</interesting>
</root>
```

You might need to change or adapt the pattern if the `very_` substring should also be extracted.

Comment: Martin, thanks much for your suggestion - it gets me a lot closer to where I need to be. Is it possible to refine it further to get only the matched piece of text in the <interesting>-tag - i.e. to not have _Some_ **interesting__text** _some more_ the italicized portions in there? I may have a very long piece of output text there, and am really only interested in the interesting bit...

Comment: @user3502342, I have edited the post and shown how to change the template for `text()` to use `analyze-string` to extract a part matching a pattern.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <xsl:template match="root">
       <xsl:element name="root">
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
           <interesting>interesting__text</interesting>
           <interesting>very_interesting__text</interesting>

       </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="b[1]"/>
    <xsl:template match="b[2]"/>
    <xsl:template match="b[3]">
        <xsl:element name="b">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="e">
        <xsl:element name="e">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="f">
        <xsl:element name="f">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="h">
        <xsl:element name="h">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="g">
        <xsl:element name="g">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: add details to your answer what you wants to do here